# Assign value to the new column based on the other columns value pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This question seems repetition and answered before but it is a bit tricky.

Let us say I have the following data frame.

```
Id     Col_1
1     aaa 
1     ccc 
2     bbb 
3     aa
```

Based on the value column Id and Col_1 I want create new column and assign new value by checking the existence of `aa` in Col_1. And this value should be applied based on the `Id` means if they have same Id.

The expected result:

```
Id   Col_1  New_Column
1     aaa    aa
1     ccc    aa
2     bbb    
3     aa    aa
```

I tried it with this:

```
df['New_Column'] = ((df['Id']==1) | df['Col_1'].str.contains('aa')).map({True:'aa', False:''})
```

and the result is

```
Id   Col_1  New_Column
1     aaa    aa
1     ccc    
2     bbb    
3     aa    aa
```

But as I mentioned it above, I want to assign `aa` on the new column with the same Id as well.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for get mask for all groups with at least one `aaa`:

```
mask = df['Col_1'].str.contains('aa').groupby(df['Id']).transform('any')
```

Alternative with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and filtering `Id` values by `aa`:

```
mask = df['Id'].isin(df.loc[df['Col_1'].str.contains('aa'), 'Id'])
```

---

```
df['New_Column'] = np.where(mask, 'aa','')
print (df)
   Id Col_1 New_Column
0   1   aaa         aa
1   1   ccc         aa
2   2   bbb           
3   3    aa         aa
```

EDIT:

```
mask1 = df['Id'].isin(df.loc[df['Col_1'].str.contains('aa'), 'Id'])
mask2 = df['Id'].isin(df.loc[df['Col_1'].str.contains('bb'), 'Id'])

df['New_Column'] = np.select([mask1, mask2], ['aa','bb'],'')
print (df)
   Id Col_1 New_Column
0   1   aaa         aa
1   1   ccc         aa
2   2   bbb         bb
3   3    aa         aa
```

Comment: OK. But is that possible to do without assigning a value to this ```(df['Id']==1)```.  Because I want to check the existence of ```aa`` and if it exists and they have similar Id, I want to assign that value with that.

Comment: @Kapital - understand, give me a sec.

Comment: I am expanding it and one more question: what if I want to assign ```bb``` also to the new column with the corresponding Id?

Comment: @Kapital - Do yo uthink same solution like above, only for `bb` ? Then is necessary copy solution and change `aa` to `bb`.

Comment: I would like to have both aa and bb. Do you think is that doable?

Comment: I am getting an error here ```mask1 = df['Id'].isin(df.loc[df['Col_1'].str.contains('aa'), 'Id'])```.  The error: ```ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

Comment: @Kapital - Then use `na=False` like `mask1 = df['Id'].isin(df.loc[df['Col_1'].str.contains('aa', na=False), 'Id'])`